# WordPress visual composer error after migrate to the new web server

Tags: html, css, wordpress, visual-composer

I am having WordPress error after migrate to the new web server. the visual composer elements, all tags[/vc_column_text] shown in the preview web page.

[image]

please let me know how to solve this?

Comment: Do you have a error log on the server? What's your previous setup? And your new server setup? What PHP and Wordpress versions were/are you using?

Comment: I don't see any errors here, did you install visual composer and are you using the same theme?

Comment: I am using the same theme and working environment previously windows 10 but now migrate to Debian 9. PHP version is the same as previous(PHP7.2).